# Adjust <div> in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to solve 2 issues in the picture below:
a) adjust space between the image and the text (red rectangle) 
b) put away at the bottom line of the image the link called "enviar" (green rectangle with the arrow)

[image]

I'm using Bootstrap style and I tried a lot of different solutions but I'm really stuck.

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="col-md-6 order-md-3 mb-4">
      <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
        <span class="text-muted">Meu carrinho</span>
        <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">3</span>
      </h4>
      <ul class="list-group mb-3">
        {% for item in cart %}
        <div class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
            <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" class="img-bg margem">
          <div style="margin-right: 20px;float:right;padding-left: 0;">
            <h6 class="my-0">{{ item.category }}</h6>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ item.description|linebreaks }}</small>
          </div>
          <span class="text-muted">{{ item.sell_price }}
          <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_remove' item.id %}" method="post">
              <input type="image" src="{% static 'remove.png' %}" class="img-sm">
              {% csrf_token %}
          </form>
          </span>

        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
          <span>Total</span>
          <strong>R$ {{ cart.get_total_price }}</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr class="mb-4">

      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Finalizar pedido</button>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: please add your Css and JS codes. also if you provide us a jsfiddle of your work we can help you faster and better.

Comment: by the way, did you try to give them `margin-left` with `float-left`

Comment: mkafiyan, I'm working with Bootstrap, so if I can overwrite it, I think it would be better! And yes, I tried margin-left with no success!

Comment: I need to see your code! don't you upload your website any where?

Comment: Just dont use bootsttrap... I think you can manage to do it without it, especially since its overused. Try using tailwind, or try to make without any of these. I know you can do it. As the saying goes: 'The more original, the better'